# Parsing a String with a specified grammar

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, bnf

How do I parse a String in Java with a specified grammar?

Let's say I have this eBNF grammar:

```
object  = "O:", natural_number, ":", value, ":", natural_number, ":{", { element }, "}";
value = '"' , character , { character } , '"';
element = string | boolean | array | empty_element, ";" ;
empty_element = "N" ;
string = "s:", natural_number, ":", value ;
boolean = "b:". "0" | "1" ;
array = "a:" ;

etc. etc. won't specify it in full here
```

How do I let Java handle parsing such a String into a usable tree?

Comment: By writing a method that does exactly that? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Well, I could write a method that does a lot of substrings or regexes, but maybe there is something more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to parse eBNF, do not bother yourself to write it.